# Can I include OFL font files in a document template that I want to sell?

Tags: fonts, word-template

I'm not sure if the OFL license allows for including the font in a WORD document that I would like to sell. For example, on Etsy, you can buy a CV template that uses OFL fonts. Some sellers include font installation files in a single .zip file, while others provide a link for downloading the font separately. Are both cases legal under the OFL license?

On website sil.org in FAQ found Question: 1.15 “What about distributing fonts with a document? Within a compressed folder structure? Is it distribution, bundling or embedding?
And answer: “Certain document formats may allow the inclusion of an unmodified font within their file structure which may consist of a compressed folder containing the various resources forming the document (such as pictures and thumbnails). Including fonts within such a structure is understood as being different from embedding but rather similar to bundling (or mere aggregation) which the license explicitly allows. In this case the font is conveyed unchanged whereas embedding a font usually transforms it from the original format. The OFL does not allow anyone to extract the font from such a structure to then redistribute it under another license. The explicit permission to redistribute and embed does not cancel the requirement for the Font Software to remain under the license chosen by its author(s). Even if the font travels inside the document as one of its assets, it should not lose its authorship information and licensing.

Does this apply in this case? It seems to me that including the font file in the document is possible, but I'm not 100% certain.